# Bash script to perform an action on each subdirectory in a directory

Tags: bash, script

Assuming I have a directory structure like

```
Dir1/
  SubDir1/
  SubDir2/
  SubDir3/
```

I'd like to be able to pass 'Dir1' to a bash script and then perform an action on all of it's subdirectories (SubDir1, SubDir2, SubDir3).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given it sounds like you're going to be running `tar`, the best way is probably:

```
basedir=$1
for dir in "$basedir"/*; do
    if test -d "$dir"; then
        tar -cvf "$dir".tar "$dir"
        rm -r "$dir"
    fi
done
```

If you wanted to use `find`, you should add `-maxdepth 1`, to avoid creating extra tar files.

```
basedir=$1
for dir in $(find "$basedir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d); do
    tar -cvf "$dir.tar" "$dir"
    rm -r "$dir"
done
```

Also note that in `tar -cvf`, the name of the output file comes first (right after the `f`).

Comment: Why do you suggest the second method when using 'rm' instead of the first?

Comment: Yes, I just re-ordered them.  I think the `for dir in $basedir/*` way is simpler.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks! I'm new to scripting so I wasn't sure if they were just two ways to do it or there was some other reason to use the one method over the other.

Answer (score 1):

```
find Dir1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec dosomethinghere {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So if I wanted to compress each sub directory I could use something like "find Dir1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec tar -cvf {} \;" What if I wanted to use the name of the sub dir more than once, could I use "-exec tar -cvf {} {}.BACK \;"? Finally, what if I want to run more than one command (like rm {} after the tar) - which is why I was thinking I'd have to use some sort of loop in a bash script. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GNU `find`, you can use `-execdir` parameter, e.g.:

```
find . -type d -depth 1 -execdir echo Action on $(pwd)/{} ';'
```